# undecidability of the structure $(\omega,+,2^n)$

Tags: logic, recursion

Is the structure $(\omega,+,2^n)$ undecidable? There is no easy way to define multiplication using a formula.

Comment: But which axioms you are taking? If you have defined addition via recursion using the successor function, then you can do the same to define multiplication. Maybe i don't know what is this structure:  $\omega$ stands for the set of natural numbers(finite ordinals and cardinals in set theory)?

Comment: I believe OP is saying this: Let $L$ be the first-order language with binary function symbol $+$, unary function symbol $E$. Let $T$ be the set of sentences over this language that are **true** in the natural numbers, with $+$ interpreted in the usual way, and $E(n)$ interpreted as $2^n$. Is the set $T$ recursive? Interesting qustion! It is well-known that if we omit $E$, the corresponding set $T'$ is recursive. And of course if we add $\times$, even without $E$, the corresponding set $T''$ is very very non-recursive.

Comment: Sorry for not putting down the entire question down properly. Andre's interpretation of the question is correct.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : I'm very intrested in this question, obviously I'm talking only for me when I say that your comment made the question even more "dark"(for me). You are talking of Model theory i guess, can you link me something about what did you say?Thanks :)

Comment: @MphLee: Sorry, don't really know what good is online. Yes, I was sort of using model-theoretic language, but only basic notions. The result about $+$ can be found by googling *Presburger Arithmetic*.

Comment: To pick small nits: I presume that the binary predicate equality (=) is supposed to be part of this structure?  That's what I presume from the discussion about Presburger Arithmetic, but it could stand to be explicit in the question (and I admit I ask in part because I'm left somewhat curious about related results with inequality in place of equality)...

Comment: This was asked, and answered (with accepted answer) on MathOverflow, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126318/is-the-structure-omega-2n-undecidable

Comment: Does anybody here know a book / other resources about omega structures?

Answer (score 1):

The same question was asked, by the same user, on MathOverflow, and an answer was accepted there: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126318/is-the-structure-omega-2n-undecidable .